# Top (New) Users of PSE, by year

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

Every year, the users of Puzzling Stack Exchange can be ranked by their reputation earned in that year. Every year, someone (usually one of the established users) takes the top spot in the yearly leagues, a hard-won position worthy of puzzlers' respect. Every year, some *newer* user takes the top spot among people who were *not previously ranked* in the yearly leagues: another position worthy of respect, especially when their rank is a high one, nestling among the high-rep established users.

- [**2014**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2014-01-01): top user [d'alar'cop](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2484/dalarcop), top new user [d'alar'cop](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2484/dalarcop) (rank **#1**, rep **7-8k**). First year of the site's existence.
- [**2015**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2015-01-02): top user [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor), top new user [Gamow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8874/gamow) (rank **#2**, rep **24-25k**).
- [**2016**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2016-01-02): top user [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi), top new user [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan) (rank **#2**, rep **23k**).
- [**2017**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2017-01-02): top user [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan), top new user [Mea Culpa Nay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38194/mea-culpa-nay) (rank **#21**, rep **5k**). Tough year for new users!
- [**2018**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2018-01-02): top user [Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36023/bass), top new user [El-Guest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest) (rank **#3**, rep **18-19k**).
- [**2019**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2019-01-02): top user [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino), top new user [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) (rank **#6**, rep **17-18k**).
- [**2020**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2020-01-02): top user [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv), top new user [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217/jeremy-dover) (rank **#6**, rep **15-16k**).
- [**2021**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2021-01-02): top user [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv), top new user [loopy walt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/73836/loopy-walt) (rank **#4**, rep **10-11k**). First repeat in the top user list.
- [**2022**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2022-01-02): top user [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv), top new user [Auribouros](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78764/auribouros) (rank **#7**, rep **6-7k**).
- [**2023**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2023-01-02): top user [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv), top new user [Lezzup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/84683/lezzup) (rank **#14**, rep **4-5k**).
- [**2024**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2024-01-02): come back after a year for updates.

<sub>*[super-fast voice at the end of advert]* All statistics are according to the linked Leagues pages, and may be inexact thanks to the Great Rep Reshuffle of 2019, which probably retroactively affected records. Rep figures are given approximately, both because of this and because the leagues seem slightly buggy (how can the year rep be more than the total rep?) Terms and conditions apply.</sub>

Comment: I think I'm confused by your comment about 2017. Surely a year in which the top new user had a relatively low score would be an _easy_ year for new users, in that coming in top among new users would have been easier that year than most?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Ah, but look at the rank. In 2017 only established users were getting more than 5k yearly rep, and no new user was able to break into the top 20 of the year. The yearly rep of the top few users was in a similar range to 2018-20, but the people getting that much were all old users.

Comment: But that doesn't mean it was a _tough year_ for new users, it means that new users didn't do so well. That _could_ be because it was harder to do well, which would count as a "tough year" but the fact that the top few users did about as well as usual suggests not. I think we maybe just didn't have as many new users, or no one particularly skilled happened to turn up that year, or they turned up part-way through the year, or something like that.

Comment: Doesn't this ranking method favor users who join the site early in the calendar year?

Comment: I *know* I'm quite late to the party, but year rep is bigger than total rep because of bounties mostly. The amount of reputation used by bounties (and other actions needing the user to "pay" some of its reputation, don't lower the total amount gained.